# Does Java set the Oracle session timezone automatically?

Tags: java, oracle

Ran into an odd problem a bit ago that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.

Our Oracle10g database's timezone is GMT.  That's the timezone of the server it runs on.  If I connect to the database and do a `SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL` via a Java app, it tells me `-04:00` (US/Eastern).  If I do the same thing from a C# app or a Perl script, it tells me `+00:00` (GMT).  None of them explicitly set the session timezone.  It looks like Java is setting the session timezone to whatever the timezone is on the system that is executing the Java app.

So why is it different from a Java connection?  What does it do that's different?  And is there a way to keep it from setting that session timezone value by itself (if that's what it's doing)?

This is causing issues with a couple of procs.  I can get around the issue by issuing an `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE...` call, but why is that necessary from Java but not Perl or C#?  What's different?

Comment: Dates, timestamps, or timestamps with [local] time zone? Not entirely relevant to your question but I wouldn't expect dates to be adjusted. I *think* Java will set the time zone from the locale, so you could maybe force that to UK - though you'd still see a GMT/BST split, I suppose.

Comment: @DaveKub As Alex Poole commented, it is important to use precise terminology with regard to database data types. Especially so with date-time as there are several types with different behavior both in the SQL spec and in various proprietary extensions. So please fix your Question.

Comment: As Alex also pointed out, it's not relevant to my question.  The actual question is why is the session timezone different when Java connects to the db than it is from C# or Perl?  What does Java do differently?  The rest of my text is merely background.

Comment: I've completely re-written the question to be more direct and eliminate non-essential bits.  Hopefully it makes more sense now.